# best methodology to create a user login

Tags: authentication, user-experience

Please tell me the best methodology to create the user login using the following details.

- First name
- Last name
- DOB

I need more readable and should not be duplicated user login. If the above details is not much or not worth to create a user login, please let me know, what details are required to create the user login in the best way?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this article for some great advice:

[**Innovative Techniques To Simplify Sign-Ups and Log-Ins**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/05/innovative-techniques-to-simplify-signups-and-logins/)

Here's a summary:

- Allow Users to Log in With Their Email Address
- Log Users in Without Leaving the Page
- Auto-Focus the First Text Field
- Allow Users to Unmask Their Password
- Use a Question Mark Icon for the Password Recovery Link
- Make the “Submit” Button as Wide as the Text Fields
- Allow Users to Log in Via Facebook, Twitter or OpenID

See also [**The Definitive Guide To Website Authentication**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication/) here on Stackoverflow.

Topics include:

- how to log in
- how to remain logged in
- how to store passwords
- using secret questions
- forgotten password functionality
- OpenID
- "Remember me" checkbox
- Browser autocompletion of usernames and passwords
- secret urls (public urls protected by digest)
- checking password strength
- email validation